# Taylor expansion on PRML(5.28)

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, hessian-matrix

I'm reading PRML and I have a question,don't solve by myself.
So, please anyone help me.

[PRML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf)

Q:Why following third time is not multiplied with $E(\boldsymbol{\hat{w}})$

$\cfrac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{\hat{w}} )^\mathrm{T} E(\boldsymbol{\hat{w}}) \boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{\hat{w}})$

$E(\boldsymbol{w}) \simeq E(\boldsymbol{\hat{w}}) + ( \boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{\hat{w}} )^\mathrm{T} \boldsymbol{b} + \cfrac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{\hat{w}} )^\mathrm{T} \boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{\hat{w}})　\cdots(5.28) $

$ \boldsymbol{b} \equiv \nabla E \,|_{w=\hat{w}} \, \cdots(5.29)$

[Taylor series](https://mathinsight.org/taylors_theorem_multivariable_introduction)

$f(\boldsymbol{x}) \approx f(\boldsymbol{a}) + Df(\boldsymbol{a}) (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a})
   +  \frac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a})^T Hf(\boldsymbol{a}) (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a}).$

Comment: A) For all we know $E(\hat w)$ might be zero, rendering that term useless. B) Why should it be multiplied? The only effect would be a rescaling of the matrix $H$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual (=single variable) Taylor series? With several variable Taylor series the vector $\mathbf{b}$ consists of the first order partial derivatives, the matrix $H$ contains the second order partial derivatives etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: That $Hf(a)$ is **NOT** a matrix $H$ multiplied by $f(a)$. It is the Hessian of the function $f$ evaluated at the point $a$. It is probably better to typeset it differently. Like $H(f)(a)$ or $H_f(a)$. Possibly $(Hf)(a)$.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the author of the text abbreviated $H(E)$ to just $H$.

Comment: I think I get it and I'll study about it to become clear.